# Error in logstash configuration file

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

My configuration file has input defined as:

```
input {
    file {
        path => “/Users/user/Desktop/user/apache_logs”
    }
}
```

configtest throws me error :

```
The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of #, ", ', -, [, { at line 3, column 11 (byte 27) after input {
    file {
        path =>  {:level=>:fatal}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using ASCII double quotes characters, i.e. you're using `”` instead of `"`

Try this instead:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/user/Desktop/user/apache_logs"
    }
}
```